# Best Java MVC framework for handling large amount of data

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I joined as  an Internship trainee. So they told me to re-engineer a  website using Java + MySQL.  The site have to handle huge amount of data and also need to generate reports.
I Googled  alot about Java Framework.  Found Hibernate. And I don't know whether it is suitable for my purpose. Is any other frameworks are there ?
Helps are appreciated.

Comment: Hibernate is an ORM framework, not MVC.  If you're doing a LOT of data manipulation, it will not perform very well either.  You could look into Spring...?  I would ask your supervisor...

Comment: @jgitter  OK. Yes. I need Java MVC Framework. I saw Spring, JSF, Struts, Play etc. My question which can handle large amount of data with Mysql.

Comment: I hate to be glib, but the answer is "all of them".

Comment: It would be nice to precise what you mean by "large amount of data", maybe it's not so large after all.

Comment: @JakubHr  Details of 4 lakh employees. It includes much manipulation and generation of reports in .xcf format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hibernate is not a MVC framework it is an ORM that is used to handle persistence layer of any application. For MVC, there are many choices like struts,springs,jsf etc. In my opinion you shall go with Spring MVC due to the strong integration aspect of springs. You can use Hibernate with Springs very well.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

There are lots of tutorials available online and on spring's site. [here is one of the useful link](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)

Comment: Yeah this helps. Let me ask a question because I am new in this. What about the learning cycle if you know Java and Experienced in working with MVC Frameworks..? And also could you please refer some useful links to head start with Spring..?

Comment: @Sanjee  he is  Internship trainee and i think you should know spring mvc learning curve is more and complex then other Java frame wroks

Comment: updated with a link for learing